Docker Does Not Recognize Container Files
I had a VM run in Sangfor HCI ( uses openstack I think ). Inside it , docker was running 2 containers. the containers were run using docker-compose. I turned the machine off and exported it to an OVA file. I converted the OVA file to OVF ( vmdk ) and imported it in VMware vCenter. Now that I have the machine back up again, when I run these commands the output shows nothing :
docker ps -a
docker ps -a -q
docker image ls
docker images


I have no idea what has happened. the files of the containers are still in /var/lib/docker/containers and the files of images are still in /var/lib/docker/image
but these commands show nothing.I checked the storage driver of docker and it is still overlay2 and hasn't changed.
I tried backing up the whole /var/lib/docker folder and letting docker rebuild it and then copying my files from the backup folder into it again but still the commands show no output. i did the same thing for /var/lib/docker/image and /var/lib/docker/containers
Still no result.
I also changed the ownership of all files in /var/lib/docker to the user : docker
And changed their permissions to 755. Still doesn't work.

I checked the status of the docker.servie service and it shows 2 errors in it's logs.
These are the errors :
Dec 22 14:16:30 snipe-it dockerd[9638]: time="2024-12-22T14:16:30.541799894+03:30" level=error msg="failed to load container mount" container=076e5c1c57a579ed81ea40abbc6f94dfb0a0575a36c7e02c5f61871d2bda26a0 error="mount does not exist"

Dec 22 14:16:30 snipe-it dockerd[9638]: time="2024-12-22T14:16:30.541894861+03:30" level=error msg="failed to load container mount" container=3b5c5b19c60d36dbc281ad3933d7a1f48fd92a7ca8389d90bcc039bc3f16000e error="mount does not exist"


I would appreciate your help, if you can give a solution, thanks

Hard to help if you don't tell us how you run your containers. Please provide a minimal reproducible example
